# mysql syntax error for update rows

Tags: mysql, database

```
update amazon-crawler set `flag_images`= '0' where `id`='966'
```

i get #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-crawler set `flag_images`= '0' where `id`='966'' at line 1
why syntax error?
amazon-crawler is the table
flag images and id are columns

Comment: Can you add the column types?

Comment: Never use '-' as part of a table/column identifier. It's potentially disastrous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the hyphen in the table name is causing problems, because it is an arithmetic operator.  Try also escaping the table name:

```
UPDATE `amazon-crawler` SET `flag_images`= '0' WHERE `id` = '966';
```

Note that you should try to avoid using backticks in your query, unless absolutely needed.  Using backticks means that *any* name would potentially work, even one which happens to be a MySQL reserved keyword.  Also, I'm guessing that `flag_images` and `id` are numeric columns, in which case you should be comparing them against numbers, not strings.  So I would write your update as this:

```
UPDATE `amazon-crawler` SET flag_images= 0 WHERE id = 966;
```

Here, only the table name has to appear in backticks.